# PIVOT without aggregate converting 2X2 Table

Tags: sql, unpivot

I have the following table named as **Customer**:

[image: number name 123 Andy]

and I want to convert it into this:

[image: name Andy number 123]

How can I do it using pivot on SQL?

I've tried the following but it didn't work out:

```
SELECT name, Andy
FROM
(
  SELECT number, name
  FROM Customer
)
t
pivot
(number(123)
FOR name IN (Andy))
AS pivot_table;
```

Could anyone please tell what did I do wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database?

For SQL Server I would do:

```
SELECT IIF(n = 1, 'Name', 'Number') [ColumnName]
     , IIF(n = 1, [Name], CAST([number] AS VARCHAR(100))) [Value]
FROM Customer  a
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2)) b (n)
```

Comment: This is a database of all customers and their customer ID.

I don't understand here:
CAST([number] AS VARCHAR(100))) [Value]
And also  (VALUES (1), (2)) b (n). 
What do you mean with those? What should I put in the formula?

Comment: I expect the Customer table to be of the form "[Name] varchar(100), Number int". If that is the case and you are using SQL Server then the staement above returns a dataset with two columns, One containing the column name (Name or Number), the other the value. I am not using the pivot command to pivot the table, but construct the pivot using a table with two values (1,2).

Comment: If you are using another database system than SQL Server, then the query will look different as the syntax varies between DBMS's.

Comment: so with my tables above, I tried to do the syntax below:
SELECT IIF(n = 1, 'Name', 'Number') [Name]
     , IIF(n = 1, [Name], CAST([number] AS VARCHAR(100))) [123]
FROM Customer  a
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2)) b (n)
and still didn't work..

Comment: I did this in the beginning:
SELECT number, name
FROM Customer
where number = 123

because I only need this one particular customer to change the column.

Then I got the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/egARN.png

And I want to change that into:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1d2s.png

Hope it clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is *unpivot* the data.  In SQL Server, I recommend `CROSS APPLY` -- the syntax for a lateral join:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM Customer c CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('Name', Name),
             ('Number', CAST(number as VARCHAR(255)))
     ) v(col, value);
```

Comment: I'm confused on this part:
 (VALUES ('Name', Name),
             ('Number', CAST(number as VARCHAR(255)))
     ) v(col, value);

Which one should I put "Name" and which one is "Andy"?
Also the value, where do I put 123 and where do I write "Number"?

Comment: @ellawidya . . . I'm confused by your confusion.  `'Andy'` is a value in a column, so it is `Name`.  `'Name'` is the name of a column, which is why it is a constant.